# Resize QDialog at a runtime

Tags: qt, user-interface, resize, qdialog, qsizepolicy

I have a QDialog subclass containing some options of my application. Some of the options are core, the other are advanced, so I decided to put them into separeted checkable QGroupBox.
[image]
I want my dialog to shrink verticaly when the user checked off advanced options box, but I can't find the way to do it properly - the dialog size stays exactle the same
[image]
I set dialog's size policy to *Expanding*, tried to call `adjustSize()` and tried to call `resize()` method - nothing helps. I can't resize programmaticaly dialog to be smaller then it's current size (it only can become larger). At the same time, it is possible to resize it manualy.
[image]
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you hide/show any widgets inside the groupbox when you check/uncheck it?

Comment: Maybe you need to hide widgets that aren't necessary at the moment and show them on expanding the dialog? You can take a look at "Dynamic Layouts Example" among Qt examples.

Comment: The `adjustSize()` should do the job. How do you hide those additional widgets and how do you restore them?

Comment: @Googie, yes, exactly, I have connected GroupBox *clicked()* signal with my own slot and hide/show widgets inside it according to GroupBox's *isChecked()* method.

Comment: I know that it should...The docs say so, but it don't

Comment: Try removing/adding them from/to the group's layout. I'm pretty sure that the layout gives the wrong `sizeHint()`, because it still thinks it has widgets to be contained and displayed. After removing them, call `adjustSize()` on dialog.

Comment: @Googie I'll try to do it, but I don't think so - GroupBox is shinking after checking off

Comment: Did you try restoring size policy to `Preferred`? I think it should fit better for this case.

Comment: @Googie I have tried to remove widgets from layout and to set size policy to `Preferred`, but unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: IS there a chance you paste a piece of code (by editing your original question) where you do the hiding/showing widgets? The entire slot for checking/unchecking group would be nice.

Comment: Do you need manual resize? 
If not, you can add _layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);_ to the dialog constructor, then the layout takes over the responsibility to automatically resize when widgets are shown or hidden.

Comment: @Zlatomir, thank you, that is it! Can you please write an answer for my question - I'd like to accept it, maybe it will be usefull for somebody else. Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't need manual resize, you can add

```
layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

to the dialog constructor, then the layout takes over the responsibility to automatically resize when widgets are shown or hidden.

Comment: This saves a ton of headache trying to manage ui sizing, Thanks.