# Change the size of a QDialog after it's content has been changed programatically

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

This question is about the very same problem described in [Resize QDialog at a runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693181/resize-qdialog-at-a-runtime), but the answer there does not fit my needs.

```
layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

does the trick that the QDialog resizes itself if it's content is changed. But the possibility to resize the dialog manually is lost doing so.

Is there a way to resize a QDialog programatically after some content has been hidden other than setting the main layout's size constraint to `QLayout::SetFixedSize`? I tried all kind of code, including saving the geometry before showing the additional widgets and re-setting this very geometry after hiding them, but no matter what I do, nothing happens.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Is the problem that the dialog does not *shrink* after hiding widgets or what?

Comment: Exactly. That's it :-) Or more general: it silenty ignores all my attempts to set another (smaller) size.

Comment: Did you try changing the layout's size constraint policy after hiding the widgets ? For example to minimum size.

Comment: Resizing the dialog to a smaller size is still ignored.

Comment: As in, `dialog->resize(dialog->sizeHint())` ?

Comment: I saved the original geometry from before showing the hidden widgets in a member variable, and tried to re-set this very geometry after hiding the widgets again.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?  What did you end up doing?

Comment: I think I did, but I don't know anymore which specific case I described here so that I could look into the code. Most probably, I used some QTimer::singleShot(0, [this] { ... }) lambda call to resize the dialog after being sure everything has been drawn and the geometry was updated.